# Call function for different parametres

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am making a form with html and javascript. But I want to change focus when I click in the input text. i have build a function, but how can I make this function global, in order to use it for the other input text...not to build a function for each input text..

My function is this:

```
function changefocus() {
    var pass = document.getElementById('pass_id');
        if (pass.value == 'Password' ){
    pass.value = '';
    pass.style.color='#000'

        }}
```

and the part of html is this:

```
<input type="text" id="pass_id" name="pass" value="Password" required="required"
        onfocus="changefocus()">
```

I try to solve my proble like this, but this doesnt function...
I give a parameter to my function

```
function changefocus(a) {
        var pass = document.getElementById('a');
            if (pass.value == 'Password' ){
        pass.value = '';
        pass.style.color='#000'

            }}
```

and then I change the html part like below:

```
  <input type="text" id="pass_id" name="pass" value="Password" required="required"
            onfocus="changefocus(pass_id)">
```

Could you please help me...How can I solve this? Thanks in advance

Now I want the input text not to be empty when I leave the input text without writting anything...I am trying to use onchange() like below, but it does function:

```
function fillemptyform(pass2) {

        if (pass2.value.length==0 ){
    pass2.value = 'Password';
    pass2.style.color='#000';

        }}

<input type="text" id="pass_id" name="pass" value="Password" required="required"
        onfocus="changefocus(this)" onchange="fillemptyform(this)">
```

How can I do this?

Comment: It looks like you're implementing a placeholder. Why don't you just use the HTML5 `placeholder` attribute?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to quote the ID when calling the `changefocus` function, and *not* quote it when using the parameter variable.

```
function changefocus(a) {
    var pass = document.getElementById(a);
    if (pass.value == 'Password' ){
        pass.value = '';
        pass.style.color='#000'
    }
}

<input type="text" id="pass_id" name="pass" value="Password" required="required"
        onfocus="changefocus('pass_id')">
```

If the ID will always be the element that contains the `onfocus` attribute, you could do it like this:

```
<input type="text" id="pass_id" name="pass" value="Password" required="required"
        onfocus="changefocus(this)">

function changefocus(pass) {
    if (pass.value == 'Password' ){
        pass.value = '';
        pass.style.color='#000'
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank a lot...You help me so much. But if I want that when I move from the input text where I am focus without writting anything, I want the input text to take again the value password, not to be empty? How can i do this? I am trying to use onchange, but it does not function...

Comment: I publish above my new function...Please can you help me

Comment: Use `onblur` instead of `onchange`. Because if the form is initially blank and you leave it blank, it doesn't change.

Answer (score 0):

Pass `this` to the function as an argument.  `this` will be assigned the element that fired the event.

**HTML**

```
   <input type="text" id="pass_id" name="pass" value="Password" required="required"
            onfocus="changefocus(this)">
```

**Javascript**

```
function changefocus(elem) {
    if (elem.value == 'Password' ){
        elem.value = '';
        elem.style.color='#000'
    }
 }
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/Vu3RR/